# "operator does not exist: bigint = character varying" when using Where.In(.., Seq[Long])

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

We are trying to run a where in command on a bigint column of postgres table

building a where query using this function

```
def buildWhere(Ids: Seq[Long]): Where = {
    val whereIds =

      if (Ids.nonEmpty) {
        Where.In("p.id", Ids.toSet)
      } else {
        Where.Empty
      }

Where.and(whereIds)
}
```

Id's data_type is bigint but getting this exception 
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying

I'm passing a scala Long for bigint but not sure where it is converting it to character could someone please point us in the right direction

Comment: i tried a Scala BigInt it's not working still getting the same error

Comment: @user2864740 database column is bigint

Comment: When Where.In is replaced with Where.Empty, does the exception "go away"? Add this detail to the question, which makes it possible to reason about other contexts being (or not being) present.

Comment: @user2864740 it has a sql statement for which this where is added and then converted toString before execution ...but i was able to isolate the issue to the where clause (because the sql on it's own is running fine)